Implementation Qisas & Hadd on Slave
Who implements the punishment of Qisas or Hadd if the convict is a slave? Is it Master of Slave or a person appointed by the Qadhi?
Specifically Want to Know the position of Hanbali Madhab.

جزاك الله خيراً
